# Editing Kernel configuration file

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, serial-port

I'm trying to compile uplcom driver for Ubuntu 12.04 for USB support of PL-2303HX serial adaptor using the following link.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man4/uplcom.4freebsd.html

But, I don't have any idea whatsoever about how to edit my kernel configuration file. Any help?

Comment: Do you really need it as a part of kernel? Why don't use it just as a kernel module?

Comment: No you are not compiling uplcom, game4cesc. The page you refer to does not provide a link to the driver (the file you download is the roff-version of the manpage). Even if you find the source code, it is unlikely to compile against 12.04, given that it is so very old: the file loader.conf does not exist in 12.04, so you cannot install it. I suggest you buy a new USB-serial adapter, they are less than 10 bucks.